# Encryption on the fly

Tags: sql-server, encryption

here is something interesting that I have been asked. It has to do with the encryption of data in a non encrypted database.

The story has as follows. We have a database, not encrypted and also none column encrypted in any of its tables. Now, we'd like to control the trafic of the data depending on who is asking for this. Let me explain more clear:

We have a table with the name: `table1`
This table has one column with the name: `SName`

We'd like to reach the following result. A user connected to the SQL Server Management Studio if runs the following query:

`select * from table1`

to take no result or if he/she takes a result, this result to be scrambled. 
Now from inside the application the table should exchange data from/to the application in the normal mode.

Do you know if there is a setting, or an implementation or an external tool that can provide this functionality?

I think that this is quite interesting case!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use permissions to stop that person reading the table at all.

Or use a VIEW to hide the table and have a WHERE clause in that that applies a filter silently: this could refer to another table with a list of approved users.

This isn't really an encryption (well, obfuscation in this case) issue.

Comment: Yes, this could be a solution but we want the users to be able to see the contents of that table. We do not want them to be able to read these specific columns.

Comment: If you want to make certain columns completely unreadable to them at all times, then you can deny select on specific columns. If you only want them to be able to read the columns under certain circumstances, use a view as @gbn suggests.

Comment: Note that DENY won't work inside a stored procedure because of ownership chaining. In your case, use views and permissions to hide columns. And you can use a CASE too to check for rights to see a column